# Cursor position in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

In a google Spreadsheet the cursor is always behind the last letter not in front. How can I change that?

Answer (score -3):

It is a very easy task to add the position of cursor to the Google Spreadsheet. It can be done in an easy way, but eliminating the various text is the risk of changes occur lost in the different editions on the same document.
In the research I found, most users are experiencing the cursor in a Google Spreadsheet is not in the proper alignment. So it is the problem that the placement of the text will not match to the actual text. So you have set your browser to set the cursor on the Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: I fail to see how this answer the question. Could you rewrite your answer to make it clearer?